# Trying to use break inside a while loop

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying for is to exit the loop when a condition meets (if not exists block) while printing the statement; else to continue with the while loop. I get the syntax error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Here is the code snippet:

```
WHILE @currentrow < @rows
BEGIN
SET @currentrow = @currentrow + 1

SELECT @selectcol = sysid
FROM @TableVar
WHERE id = @currentrow

SELECT @sysid =  @selectcol 

IF NOT EXISTS (
SELECT field_id
FROM fields
WHERE sys_id = @sysid
    AND NAME = @field_name
)
 PRINT cast(@field_name AS VARCHAR) + ' not found in the       business area ' + cast(@sysid AS VARCHAR)

BREAK

ELSE

CONTINUE

[While loop continues]
```

Comment: "seems to be a syntax error"? Specifically, what is the error message? Please update your question with this info.

Comment: Updated. The problem is with the placement of else

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this logic - either this `IF` block comes at the end of the loop body (in which case `CONTINUE` is pointless - that's what the loop is going to do anyway) or the rest of the loop is unreachable (since you always either `BREAK` or `CONTINUE`).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Turns out break and continue do not work as I thought they do. You are right, rest of my while loop is unreachable if I use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need an `END` keyword at the end:

```
WHILE @currentrow < @rows
    BEGIN
        SET @currentrow = @currentrow + 1

        SELECT @selectcol = sysid
        FROM @TableVar
        WHERE id = @currentrow

        SELECT @sysid =  @selectcol 

        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT field_id FROM fields WHERE sys_id = @sysid AND NAME = @field_name)
            BEGIN
                PRINT CAST(@field_name AS VARCHAR) + ' not found in the business area ' + CAST(@sysid AS VARCHAR)
                BREAK
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                CONTINUE
            END
    END
```

To avoid errors like this in your logical flow, use whitespace effectively to clearly see where opening and closing statements should go.

Comment: I have edited my question with the error message. It is not a problem with END keyword, I have just posted a snippet. The while loop is supposed to "continue" afterwards.

Comment: And it will continue until your expression is false in the `WHILE` loop declaration...

Comment: I've edited my answer, I'd follow the BOL syntax if you get stuck again.